# How to draw a grid like this using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I am preparing some presentations using `Beamer` and `XeLaTeX`. There are a few images which I would like to draw using `TikZ`, as follows:

[image]

My sample presentation goes as follows:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=149,presentation,10pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{204,204,204}
\definecolor{tomato}{RGB}{231,76,60}
\definecolor{snow}{RGB}{236,240,241}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=snow}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[R/.style={fill=lightgray,color=lightgray},L/.style={-,line width=2pt,color=tomato}]
        \node (f) at (-0.5,2) [rotate=90] {Frequency};
        \node (h) at (5,6) {\bf{Histogram of rdist}};
        \node (r) at (5.5,-0.5) {rdist};
        \draw [R] (0,3.75) rectangle (1,0);
        \draw [L] (3,0) -- (3,5);
        \draw [R] (3.05,4.9) rectangle (4.05,0);
        \draw [R] (4.1,4.9) rectangle (5.1,0);
        \draw [R] (5.15,1.75) rectangle (6.15,0);
        \draw [R] (8.15,1.75) rectangle (9.15,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And which produces below output:

[image]

Now I do not know how to draw the `axes`.

I am new to TikZ...to get accustomed with it, I already have started to read the manual (pgfmanual.pdf) from start...it is big and I am learning many new ideas. Based on that I have also prepared some diagrams. But, for the graph plot I am nearly clueless.

It would be highly appreciable if someone guides me in a step by step mode on the topic. As I already mentioned I am learning TikZ.

Comment: can you please shorten your example to the most related part to your question? A [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be sufficient to answer your question.

Comment: Well, this code isn't even a MWE!

Comment: Your MWE does not compile, you cannot use font commands in beamer colour definitions. You also don't need the `graphicx` package with beamer, nor `etoolbox` if your beamer version if reasonable up-to-date

Comment: That said, you could have a look at the `pgfplots` package to plot such bar plots

Comment: A nice example how to draw a bar plot in pgfplots: http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/bar-plot/

Comment: My previous code compiles correctly, using `XeLaTeX `...but i have shorten the example for clarity...sorry the confusion...

Comment: @Cylian the line `\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{fg=dodgerblue,series=\bfseries,size=\Huge}` should definitely through an error about `Package keyval Error: series undefined.`

Comment: @samcarter: thank you for pointing that out...i have edited the question and provided specific question...sorry for the inconveniences...

Comment: @Cylian The answer is: use pgfplots and let the package draw the axis for you. See an example in the link I posted earlier

Comment: @samcarter: yes i have checked the `pgfplots.pdf`....but i would like to draw the axes without using `pgfplots` at all...are there any workaround...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see only the axes are missing. While it is arguably more convenient to draw them with pgfplots, it is easy enough to implement them using Ti*k*Z "only". (Some seemingly unnecessary stretches are in because otherwise the line joins at the ends of the axes would not look good.)

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=149,presentation,10pt]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{204,204,204}
\definecolor{tomato}{RGB}{231,76,60}
\definecolor{snow}{RGB}{236,240,241}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=snow}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[R/.style={fill=lightgray,color=lightgray},L/.style={-,line width=2pt,color=tomato}]
        \node (f) at (-1.2,2) [rotate=90] {Frequency};
        \node[font=\bfseries] (h) at (5,6) {Histogram of rdist};
        \node (r) at (5.5,-1.5) {rdist};
        \draw [R] (0,3.75) rectangle (1,0);
        \draw [L] (3,0) -- (3,5);
        \draw [R] (3.05,4.9) rectangle (4.05,0);
        \draw [R] (4.1,4.9) rectangle (5.1,0);
        \draw [R] (5.15,1.75) rectangle (6.15,0);
        \draw [R] (8.15,1.75) rectangle (9.15,0);
        % axes
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\vfactor}{4.9/6}
        \draw[thick] (-0.5,0) -| (-0.2,6*\vfactor)--(-0.5,6*\vfactor);
        \foreach \X in {0,...,6}
        {\draw[thick] (-0.2,\X*\vfactor) -- (-0.5,\X*\vfactor) node[left] {\X};}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\hfactor}{9.15/4}
        \draw[thick] (0,-0.5)|-(4*\hfactor,-0.2)--(4*\hfactor,-0.5);
        \foreach \X in {0,...,4}
        {\draw[thick] (\X*\hfactor,-0.2) -- (\X*\hfactor,-0.5) node[below] {\X};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]